# selecting the channel that corresponds to max duration

Tags: sas

To get the longest viewing period for a given ID I can use the following code. But, how can I also retrieve the channel that corresponds to the longest viewing period. I apologize for my pathetic attempt at formatting

```js
proc means data=new1 noprint max nway missing; 

   class ID;

   var duration;

   output out=sample_max (drop=_type_ _freq_) max=;

run;
```

Comment: Don't apologize for your formatting, figure out how to improve it.

Comment: channel name is a categorical variable and hence my dilemma

Comment: There isn't syntax highlighting for SAS, just select control-k to indent everything 4 spaces

Comment: So `channel` is a variable that varies within ID along with `duration`, and you want the `channel` that goes with the highest `duration`?

Comment: yes. working on the formatting

Comment: Look at my edit (click on the "edited X mins ago" to get edit history"); that was the 'right' way to do it.  Don't worry about syntax highlighting.

Comment: Much better. I would not do the language hint, as js is somewhat okay but just not worth that much and might confuse the issue in some ways having some-but-not-others highlighted properly.  We all on the SAS tag are used to no syntax formatting.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
proc sort data=have;
by id descending duration ;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id;
if first.id;
run;
```

That gives you the highest duration on top, one for each ID.

You could also take the PROC MEANS output and merge it to the original dataset to retrieve the row it corresponds to (silly in this case, but useful perhaps if you want things other than just max).